# why I failed in JBoos-7 Virtual Hosting with mod_proxy?

Tags: deployment, jboss, apache2, mod-proxy

I am trying to make Jboss-7 deployment work with mod_proxy on port 80, but I faced problem

1- I modified the standaloan.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true" default-web-module="filemanager">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
 <virtual-server name="AyeServer" default-web-module="mydeployemnt">
                <alias name="mydomain.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

2- I created jboss-web.xml inside WEB-INF with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_7_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <virtual-host>www.mydomain.com<virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

3- in httpd.conf I add to the end of file this content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName mydomain.com

ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/mydeployment

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/mydeployment


DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
Options -Indexes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but nothing work when I call mydomain.com

any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule !proxy_ajp_module>
      LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    </IfModule>
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

As I understand from your comments, you want to configure apache in front of JBOSS 7, to take the web requests.

You can use mod proxy apache modules with ajp protocol and enable ajp in JBOSS 7 app server. Below are the steps,

1. Enable below modules in httpd.conf of apache.

   LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

   LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so

   LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
2. Create a file proxyajp.conf and place in apache/conf folder. The file should have above xml content. Then include this file in httpd.conf.
3. Modify JBOSS 7 standalone.xml to include supprot for ajp protocol. The ajp port will be 8009.